# I want to call phtml file from Magento_Theme to static block. but it is giving some error

Tags: blocks, template, phtml, magento-2.1.9

PHTML file is located in Magento_Theme/templates/html/breadcrumbs.phtml.

I tried with the code

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html\breadcrumbs.phtml"}}
```

but it is giving error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your template path

it should be:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/breadcrumbs.phtml"}}
```

**Note: Use forward slash `/`**

Comment: still showing the same error. i added the template to the block and called through widget  "after the page header top".

Comment: You need to enable developer mode to see exact error OR check in log files

Comment: May be you need to flush cache as well!

Answer (score 1):

Custom file path

```
app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/test.phtml
```

calling in xml layout file

```
<block class=""Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"" name=""test_file"" template=""Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml""/>
```

Calling in blocks and cms pages

```
{{block class=""Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"" name=""test_file"" template=""Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml""}}
```

Calling in any phtml file

```
<?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml')) ?>
```

OR, as before

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock(""Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"")->setTemplate(""Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml"")->toHtml();?>
```